# Sharepoint - Getting selected items from ListViewByQuery Control - ASPX Site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a aspx site with a ListViewByQuery and Button control. When the button gets clicked I want to get the selected items from the ListViewByQuery control. I used the following code but the variable "selection" always has a count of 0.

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var button = $("input[id$=SaveButton]");
            button.click(function () {

                var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var selection = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

                var fileItems = [];
                var currentItem;

                for (currentItem in selectedItems) {
                    fileItems.push(currentItem);
                    context.load(currentItem, 'Id');
                }

                context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < fileItems.length; i++) {
                        alert(fileItems[i].get_id());
                    }
                }));

            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div id="pnlDiv">
        <SharePoint:ListViewByQuery runat="server" ID="MyListView" Enabled="True" />
        <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    Application Page
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"
    runat="server">
    My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

Other facts: 
- List get filled from the code behind file 
- The aspx site gets called by a event receiver ("SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl") after the edit form from a DL.

Answer (score 0):

The method `ListModule.Util.getSelectedItemsDict` (`core.js`) could be utilized for retrieving selected items in [ListViewByQuery Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listviewbyquery.aspx).

**Example 1**.

The example demonstrates how to retrieve selected items from Workflow History list (`wrkstat.aspx`)

```
function getSelectedItemsInfo(ctxNumber)
{
   var listCtx = GetListContextFromContextNumber(ctxNumber);
   return ListModule.Util.getSelectedItemsDict(listCtx);
}   

//Note: Context Number for Workflow History list on page wrkstat.aspx is 2, since it contains 2 ListViewByQuery controls on the page. If page contains only single ListViewByQuery control then Context Number is 1
var selectedItems = getSelectedItemsInfo(2); 
printItemsInfo(selectedItems);

function printItemsInfo(items)
{
    if(!items)
       return;
    for (var key in items){
      var item = items[key];
      var itemId = item.id;
      var itemType = item.fsObjType;
      console.log(String.format('Selected List Item Id: {0}',itemId));
    }            
}
```

> Note: To identify `ListViewByQuery` control the *Context Number* have to
>   be specified.  For  for Workflow History list on page `wrkstat.aspx` is
>   2, since it contains 2 `ListViewByQuery` controls on the page. If page
>   contains only single `ListViewByQuery` control then Context Number is
>   **1**

Example 2.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410681(v=office.14).aspx) collection from selected items in Workflow History list (`wrkstat.aspx`)

```
function getSelectedItems(ctxNumber, success,failure)
{
   var listCtx = GetListContextFromContextNumber(ctxNumber);
   var selectedItems = ListModule.Util.getSelectedItemsDict(listCtx);
    if(!selectedItems) {
       success(null);
       return;
    }    

   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listCtx.ListTitle);
   var listItems = [];
   for (var key in selectedItems){
      var item = selectedItems[key];
      var listItem = list.getItemById(item.id);
      context.load(listItem);
      listItems.push(listItem);
    }            

   context.executeQueryAsync(
       function () {
           success(listItems);
       },
       failure);
}

//Usage
getSelectedItems(2,printWorkflowHistory,logError);
function printWorkflowHistory(items)
{
    if(!items)
       return;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length;i++){
      var item = items[i];
      console.log(String.format('Selected List Item Id: {0}',item.get_item('Description')));
    }            
}
function logError(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```